# Digits tower power iterate

Tags: number-theory, power-towers

Stack the digits of a natural number into a power tower, iterate until only one digit remains.

**Does this iteration always terminate for any positive integer?**

Additionally specify $0^n = 0$, even when $n=0$.

For example

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_0&=58\\
f_1&=5^8=390625\\
f_2&=3^{9^{0}}=3^1=3\\
\end{aligned}
$$

---

The smallest uncalculable number is 28:

$$
\begin{aligned}
28 &\to 256 \to 39235776294252497421590\cdots\\
44 &\to \color{red}{256} \\
48 &\to 65536\\
49 &\to 262144\to6871\cdots\to28251\cdots\\
54 &\to 625 \to 7958661\cdots\\
57 &\to 78125 \to 5764801\\
65 &\to 7776 \\
66 &\to 46656 \\
67 &\to 279936\\
72 &\to \color{red}{49}\\
73 &\to 343 \to 3433683820\cdots\\
77 &\to 823543\\
78 &\to 5764801\\
85 &\to 32768\\
86 &\to 262144\\
97 &\to 4782969\\
99 &\to 387420489\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Probably this is the case : As soon as the second or the third digit is $0$ , we are done. The first digits of the power tower should behave as a pseudorandom sequence. Under this assumption the process will eventually terminate.

Comment: For the number 28 I ran into memory error in python 3.9. I guess it will terminate as we require second or third digit 0 as suggested by @Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For number $5243$, we have $5^{2^{4^3}}=5243909\dots$ which cannot terminate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).